# Octopress blank page when add backtick code block

Tags: windows-7, rubygems, octopress, rdiscount

I am wondering why I am getting blank page when I add backtick code block with specific language?

**_config.yml**

```
markdown: rdiscount
rdiscount:
  extensions:
    - autolink
    - footnotes
    - smart
pygments: false # default python pygments have been replaced by pygments.rb
```

**in my post** If I use backtick without specific language

````
```
var foo = "Hello";
```
````

that's working, page is shown normally

but When I use backtick with specific language ex.js, javascript, java

````
```js
var foo = "Hello";
```
````

It's blank page without errors.

```
[2013-12-30 17:24:46] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2013-12-30 17:24:46] INFO  ruby 1.9.3 (2013-11-22) [i386-mingw32]
[2013-12-30 17:24:46] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=7288 port=4000
Auto-regenerating enabled: source -> public
[2013-12-30 17:24:46] regeneration: 103 files changed
>>> Change detected at 17:24:47 to: screen.scss
identical public/stylesheets/screen.css

Dear developers making use of FSSM in your projects,
FSSM is essentially dead at this point. Further development will
be taking place in the new shared guard/listen project. Please
let us know if you need help transitioning! ^_^b
- Travis Tilley

>>> Compass is polling for changes. Press Ctrl-C to Stop.
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Dec/2013 17:25:06] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 - 0.8490
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Dec/2013 17:25:41] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 - 0.0040
```

I think it works fine on Ubuntu but didn't work on Windows 7
Any suggestions ?
My machine

- Windows 7 32-bit
- Ruby 1.9.3 p484
- rdiscount 2.0.7.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fenced code blocks with a language specifier are only supported in the very latest version of Discount / RDiscount (2.1.7). Make sure your RDiscount gem is >=2.1.7.

Comment: My Ubuntu machine in Rakefile gem 'rdiscount', '~> 2.0.7' also work! but Windows 7 are only work latest version

Comment: Issue `gem update rdiscount` in git Bash (for those ruby challenged as I)